# How to use the def function in IF or ELSE/ ELIF satement in python?

Tags: python

I have a sub program that uses a def option, so if i ever want to repeat the program. Eg:

```
def op1():

    print ("Something Something")
```

So I just write in the program:

```
op1()
```

which makes the program run.

Now I have a lot of subprograms each one with a different `def` so I can run them by easily.

eg:

```
def op1():

def op2():

def op3():
```

So I wanted to know how can I use this in `if-else` statement.

eg:

```
option = input ("Enter either A, B or C here: ")

if option == A:    
    def op1():    
else:    
    def op2():
```

or even

```
if option == A:    
    def op1():
elif:    
    def op2():
elif:    
    def op3():
```

Something like that, but it doesn't work. Can anyone help, Please?
Also I'm using the newer version of python if that helps 3.5.0.

Comment: Yes you can but you have to do it right and add conditions after elif. Python programming references typically explain the syntax of if else elif very well and many other useful things as well.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to define functions conditionally.

```
def op1():
   print('1')

def op2():
   print('2')

def op3():
   print('3')

if option == 'A':
   op1()
elif option == 'B'::
   op2()
else:
   op3()
```

Comment: What if i wanted to add op3() too?

Comment: Just the same: define it above, call in inside `if ... elif ... else`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your functions first but if you have multiple choices you can store references to functions in a dict then call based on what the user enters, using `dict.get` with a default function will act like your if/elif else logic:

```
def op1():
    return '1'


def op2():
    return '2'

def op3():
    return "3"


option_fs = {"A": op1, "B": op2}
option = input("Enter either A, B or C here: ").upper()
print(option_fs.get(option, op3)())
```